# How to upload .env file to gcloud by overriding default .gcloudignore settings

Tags: google-app-engine, gcloud

I am currently trying to migrate a PHP application to Google AppEngine.
Everything works, except one thing: My `.env` file is not deployed alongside my application's code files and I can't get Google Cloud to stop ignoring this file.

I have already tried to add the entry `!.env` to the file `.gcloudignore`, but this doesn't change anything. The `.env` file is simply not showing up after the deployment of the app.

In case you need more details, feel free to take a look at the corresponding [GitHub repository](https://github.com/jr-cologne/CryptoStatus).

I would be really happy if anyone has an idea how to deploy my environment variables. There might even be a completely different solution which is way better.
So, feel free to share your approach towards storing environment variables for Google AppEngine applications.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can define environment variables in the `env_variables` section of the `app.yaml` file:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/php/reference/app-yaml#defining_environment_variables

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this does not help if I want to commit the `app.yaml` file to GitHub.

Comment: Your question asked for a way to deploy your environment variables and this is the App Engine way to do this. One compelling advantage using `app.yaml` is that your environment variables aren't deployed with the application; app.yaml is used to deploy your application. You are correctly concerned about deploying `.env` to GitHub. You should also be concerned about deploying `.env` with your apps. You may wish to consider a deployment process that maps env values into `app.yaml` when you deploy.

Comment: Alright, then I need to figure out how to achieve this. Thank you for this hint. I apologize in case my question wasn't clear enough. I was just really unsure how real applications go about doing this and just chose the simple and apparently bad approach deploying the `.env` file.

Comment: You're welcome. Someone more familiar with PHP and your runtime will be able to help.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem with the deployment of a Node.js app to Google Cloud.
This was my setupt:

.env file with credentials on my personal PC but not committed to git

.env file ignored in .gitignore to not have credentials in the GitLab repo

Environment variables set in the GitLab CI/CD variables

I used the .gitlab-ci.yml to read the GitLab variables into a .env file that is created during deployment:

```
image: docker:latest

stages:
  - deploy

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  image: google/cloud-sdk
  services:
    - docker:dind
  script:
    - rm .gitignore
    - echo NODE_ENV=production > .env
    - echo SERVER_PORT=8080 >> .env
    # gcloud deployment following
```

The crucial part here was the line

```
rm .gitignore
```

It deletes the .gitignore file before packing the Docker Image. This ensures that Google Clouds docker packing does not use the .gitignore file to exclude .env again.

*Notice* that other files from .gitignore may also end up staying in your Docker image so you might want to add a .dockerignore file to clean up your image.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, which was that gcloud build was not uploading a .env file, and found that the default .gcloudignore was including my .gitgnore file, which included .env. I took .env out of my .gitgnore and then gcloud build did not ignore it. For me that was an acceptable solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using an older version of App Engine it's likely ignoring `.env` by default via [skip_files](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/legacy/standard/python/config/appref#skip_files). You can override the default behavior of `skip_files` by including a file that doesn't need to be uploaded. App Engine won't allow an empty list.

app.yaml

```
skip_files:
 - ^\.gitignore$
```

This instructs app engine to only ignore `.gitignore` instead of all dot files.